# Shiny How to dynamically select columns of imported dataset for further analysis

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying a small shiny app wherein I load a CSV file from the local directory and then select specific columns from the dataframe and use this subsetted dataframe for further data analysis.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("dataset", "Choose CSV File",
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  accept = c("text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             ".csv")),
        # Include clarifying text ----
        #helpText(em("Note: This app requires file in csv format only!!")),
        helpText(em("Note:Select all the inputs and click on button as given below to exectute the app")),
        # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
        checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
        # Input: Select separator ----
        radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                     choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                 Semicolon = ";",
                                 Tab = "\t"),
                     selected = ","),
        selectInput("select", "Select columns to display", names(datasetInput), multiple = TRUE),
        actionButton("update", "Update Data set", class = "btn-primary",style='padding:4px; font-size:120%')
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        h2('The Mydata'),
        dataTableOutput('mytable')
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    validate(need(input$dataset != "", "Please select a data set in csv format only!!!"))# custom error message on opening the app
    read.csv(input$dataset$datapath,
             header = input$header,
             sep = input$sep)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  dataset <- reactive({
    df_input<-datasetInput()
    df_input$x<-NULL
    df_input
  })

   output$mytable = renderDataTable({
     columns = names(dataset)
     if (!is.null(input$select)) {
       columns = input$select
     }
     dataset[,columns,drop=FALSE]
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Looking in some SO answers;got a few; one as given below:

[shiny allowling users to choose which columns to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784906/shiny-allowling-users-to-choose-which-columns-to-display)

But this answer, the dataset is predefined; I want to the user to download his own dataset.

I am getting the following error:

> Error in lapply(obj, function(val) { : object 'datasetInput' not found

I think somewhere I have to use an observeEvent function?

Comment: The error occurs due to the `choices` argument of the `selectInput`. `datasetInput` doesn't exist while the UI of the app is being rendered.

Comment: @Imran Ali   I know....need to knw how can i connect the uploaded csv file and display the columns of the uploaded file.....What shud be the dataset id in`selectInput` argument

Comment: You need to dynamically `renderUI`. [Dynamic selectInput in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080629/dynamic-selectinput-in-r-shiny) might help you getting started

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass values (choices) to selectizeInput() after selecting data from UI in shiny app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524036/how-to-pass-values-choices-to-selectizeinput-after-selecting-data-from-ui-in)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a variant of `server.R`; use it with akrun's `ui.R`. This one dynamically adapts the filtering choices, and allows you to add columns back by adding their column name even after clicking the button.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

server <- function(session, input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    req(input$dataset)
    read.csv(input$dataset$datapath, header = input$header,sep = input$sep)
    })

  filtereddata <- eventReactive({
      input$update
      data()
    },  {
    req(data())
    if(is.null(input$select) || input$select == "")
      data() else 
        data()[, colnames(data()) %in% input$select]
  })

  observeEvent(data(), {
    updateSelectInput(session, "select", choices=colnames(data()))
  })

  output$mytable  <- renderDataTable(filtereddata())

}
```

Answer (score 3):

We could modify it

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
```

-ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("dataset", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),
      # Include clarifying text ----
      #helpText(em("Note: This app requires file in csv format only!!")),
      helpText(em("Note:Select all the inputs and click on button as given below to exectute the app")),
      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),
      selectInput("select", "Select columns to display", c('col1', 'col2'), multiple = TRUE),
      actionButton("update", "Update Data set", class = "btn-primary",style='padding:4px; font-size:120%')
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      h2('The Mydata'),
      #tableOutput("mytable")
      DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")

    )
  )
)
```

-server

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  values <- reactiveValues(df_data = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$dataset, {
      values$df_data <- read.csv(input$dataset$datapath,
                                header = input$header,
                                sep = input$sep
                                )}

               )
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    temp <- values$df_data[input$select]
    values$df_data <- temp

  })
  output$mytable  <- renderDataTable(values$df_data)

}
```

-Run the application

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

-after updating

[image]

Comment: ALmost there,,, u r not calling the column names dynamically in `selectInput` function as u r explicitly defining column names of imported dataset.....it wont work for any other datasets......so what shud  the argument be instead of `c('col1', 'col2')`.....

Answer (score 0):

@Christoph Wolk.....excellent it Worked!

Just a small change....since i do not want to show the data as soon it is selected using browse but only when `update data set` button is clicked i commented out `outdata()`  as below"

```
filtereddata <- eventReactive({
    input$update
    #data()
    },  {
    req(data())
        if(is.null(input$select) || input$select == "")
      data() else 
        data()[, colnames(data()) %in% input$select]
  })

  observeEvent(data(), {
    updateSelectInput(session, "select", choices=colnames(data()))
  })
```

Is there a way to show a custom message instead of blank  in the main panel when the app is opened ;something like this:

`Please select a data set in csv format only`

Somewhere we need to put some sort of condition i suppose in above `filtereddata`() :

`validate(need(input$dataset != "","Please select a data set in csv format only!!!"))# custom error message on opening the app`

Solved it!!!!!

```
filtereddata <- eventReactive({
    validate(need(input$dataset != "","Please select a data set in csv format only!!!"))# custom error message on opening the app
    input$update
    #data()
    },  {
       req(data())

    if(is.null(input$select) || input$select == "")
      data() else 
        data()[, colnames(data()) %in% input$select]
  })
```

## in ui

add this to get custom colour for the error msg

```
# Custom error message with green colour ----



tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
                    .shiny-output-error-validation {
                    color: green;
                    }
                    ")))
```

[image]