# Unselect columns of imported dataset - selectInput - Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

After following suggestions there I was able to select imported columns by my own:

[Shiny How to dynamically select columns of imported dataset for further analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46010595/shiny-how-to-dynamically-select-columns-of-imported-dataset-for-further-analysis)

But I was wondering if there is an option to remove a particular column from selected. I mean, for example, I chose column by mistake and I do not want to display this column, can I remove it somehow before updating a dataframe? So basically i would like to know if there is a way to unselect options in    `selectInput`?

Comment: Could you please provide a small example of the code of how you're going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it's from the perspective of the user of your app, not the person writing it. You want your users to be able to de-select items after they select them in your `selectInput`. This is of course supported.

How users do this depends on whether you use `selectize = TRUE` or not in your `selectInput`. The default is `TRUE`.

If you use `selectize`, the user can just move the I-beam cursor before the item and press delete, or after it and press backspace.

If you don't use `selectize`, users can just click an item to deselect it.

If you want, you could use a Confirm button to have the user confirm that their selection is correct and complete before anything reactive updates.